# Slime claims input error; all parentheses match

Tags: emacs, input, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

I'm in a jiffy: just practicing manipulating lists and here is my code:

```
(defun new-strand (size type)
  (if (= 0 size)
      nil
      (case type
        ((nstrand) (cons 'x (new-strand (1- size) 'nstrand)))
        ((nlist) (cons '(x) (new-strand (1- size) 'nlist))))))

(defun locate-string (string index) 
  (if (null list)
      '(Cannot locate string: invalid index)
      (if (= index 0)
          'string
          (locate-string (cdr string) (1- index)))))

(defun new-substring (string)
  (if (> (length (car string)) 1)
      (cons (new-strand (1- (length (car string))) 'nstrand) (cdr string))
      (cons '(x) (new-substring (cdr string)))))

(defun construct-string (string index)
  (append (reverse (new-substring (cdr (locate-string
                                         (reverse string)
                                         (- (length string) index)))))
          (cons (new-strand (1+ (length (car (locate-string string index))))
                            'nstrand)
                (new-substring (cdr (locate-string string index))))))
```

Yes I know that last function is long, but I've checked parentheses by hand and via minibuffer (check-parens)...and they seem to match. So...could someone please tell me why I'm getting SB:INPUT-ERROR-IN-COMPILE-FILE?

Comment: Add a parenthesis at the very end.

Comment: Also, CCL doesn't like your `'(Cannot locate string: invalid index)`. Try to replace it with a string "Cannot locate string: invalid index".

Comment: Also, locate-string has no variable called *list*.

Comment: @x86ris: you may want to install either *paredit* or *smartparens*. Once you're using such a minor mode you really have to go out of way to get misbalanced parentheses. In addition to that a minor mode like *rainbow-delimiters-mode* may help too: because it would have been obvious that the color of your last parenthesis was not matching the one of the parenthesis before the *defun*  ^ ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recap:

1. There was a trailing parenthesis missing. You seem to have added it now.
2. `'(Cannot locate string: invalid index)` chokes because of the colon `:`
3. `locate-string` has no variable *list*. You probably meant *string*.

And why not format the last function like so:

```
(defun construct-string (string index)
  (append 
   (reverse (new-substring (cdr (locate-string (reverse string) (- (length string) index))))) 
   (cons 
    (new-strand (1+ (length (car (locate-string string index)))) 'nstrand) 
    (new-substring (cdr (locate-string string index))))))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Just wondering: is there an escape sequence that allows me to utilize a colon character in a list?                EDIT: nvm; its just like in other languages, using the backslash.

Comment: The formatting of `construct-string` in the question is better, at least now (might be edited).

Comment: @Svante Yes it was heavily edited; used to be more or less all on one line ;-)